# Защита от DDos атаки

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, ddos

Который день стараюсь защитить себя от DDos-атак, 
Пример лога конкретной атаки ниже(Каждый запрос, разный адрес).
В конкретном логе показан метод атаки который удалось обить, благодаря пользователю stackoverflow. Который посоветовал всем числовым аргументам возвращать 403.
Но атакующий начал бить по корню /. Нужен совет.

Accesslog

```html
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?8954=97930190 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?4372=94533968 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?4837=13407187 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?875=35869386 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?1490=71117968 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?7468=76369350 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?6671=74934584 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?8265=45477414 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?7806=95939600 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?2142=5032549 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?1566=20687217 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
XX.XX.X.X - - [21/Jan/2019:22:16:10 +0100] "GET /?2043=99331004 HTTP/1.1" 403 260 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
```

На сервере установлена панель VestaCP, привязан Cloudflare. 
Внешний доступ к серверу запрещен, HTTP/HTTPS открыт только для Cloudflare.